# whats mean window['Map'] in Javascript

Tags: javascript, dictionary, leaflet

im confused with window['Map'].

im using window['Map'] on leaflet maps to show layer, and it works fine.

script below :

```
layerUrl = 'http://service-tms.local-server.link/?token='+token+'&z={z}&x={x}&y={y}';
window['Map' + 'test'] = L.tileLayer(layerUrl, {opacity: 0.8});
```

My question is .. :
in http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/obj_window.asp, i dont find 'Map' as window object properties. 
Why?

Whether 'Map' is not part of window object? Where i find reference about window['Map'] ..?

Comment: I assume you're talking about _ES6's `Map`_ when you're asking about a reference? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map Please try to avoid using the identifier `Map` as the name for other pieces of code as you will cause a conflict with this _Object_

Comment: Are you asking about `window['Map']` or what you have in your code `window['Map' + 'test']`?  In both cases, these are just a means of accessing a global variable `Map` or `Maptest`.

Comment: @PaulS. yeah, im worry to use window['Map'] and it not support for all browser.. huh?

Comment: @jfriend00, im talking about window['Map'] with unique id 'test',
so i can call 
window['Maptest']
window['Maptest2']
window['Maptest3']
.. etc

Comment: That's not how the Map object works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Map` object in JavaScript appears to be experimental technology, and is not widely adopted or supported by all the major browsers yet.

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map for reference about the `Map`

Experimental APIs are dangerous to use in production environments as they may change at any time, or they may have inconsistent behaviour across different browsers.

**Edit (April 13/2017):**

It appears `window.Map` is no longer labeled as *experimental* and all major browsers at least have basic support for `Map`. The date of this change is unknown to me.

Comment: `Map` is in the ES6 draft specification.  "Early implementation" is probably a better description than "experimental".

Comment: I was just using the terminology from the MDN :)

Comment: Yeah, I know that's what MDN says.  I don't think it's the right terminology to describe something that is fully specified in the ES6 draft spec and is implemented in a lot of places already.  It's no longer "experimental".

Answer (score 3):

When JavaScript executes in the browser, the `window` object is the root scope. Because of this `window['abcd']` or `window.abcd` will refer to a global variable with the name `abcd`.

In your snippet, `window['Map' + 'test']` is used, which is the same as `window['Maptest']` or even `window.Maptest`. `Maptest` may be a global variable in your script.

As a side note, global variables are generally a bad idea and should be discouraged!